# How can I select a keypair from my keyring and prompt a password for signing transactions?

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic

As the title says, I'm trying to be able to select a keypair from my keyring prompt for a password then sign a transaction and submit to the tx pool.

How should I use the ui-keyring and keyring to achieve that?
Thanks :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a browser extension for managing accounts?

Comment: Good point, I'm using. Didn't look the documentation yet, thanks :)